# Flow scheduled jobs reach limits?

Tags: governorlimits, time-dependent-workflow

I have a scheduled Flow which runs daily and runs a good deal of queries.

Is there any kind of risk of reaching a limit (monthly or otherwise) for number of queries which can be run or the "Maximum Flow Interviews Without UI per Month" ? I'm not exactly sure what that limit is. I see that we are currently at 2.6 million of the 10 million limit.

If there is a risk of reaching query limits how would I be able to monitor that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_trigger_schedule.htm&type=5),

> The maximum number of schedule-triggered flow interviews per 24 hours is 250,000, or the number of user licenses in your org multiplied by 200, whichever is greater. One interview is created for each record retrieved by the schedule-triggered flow’s query.
> If you specify an object so that the flow runs for a batch of records, then set the time, frequency, and record conditions to avoid reaching this limit. You can use debug logs to check how many records a schedule-triggered flow runs on. Track the number of records with the FLOW_START_SCHEDULED_RECORDS event. If your org reaches the limit, Salesforce sends a flow error email.

[Maximum flow interviews without UI per month](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_usage_entitlements.htm&type=5) is a limit in which flow is triggered programmatically, without any user interaction.

You can check [Flow Limits and Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations.htm&type=5), [General Flow Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_limit.htm&type=5) and also In API version 57.0, the limit of 2000 flow elements is removed.

Unfortunately there is no direct way to monitor scheduled jobs or query limits in flows and you can consider below points.

- Monitor flow schedules.
- Consider using other automation tools in Salesforce, such as Batch jobs etc.
- Optimize flow design and if you hit limits see if you can increase org's limits.

You can check [Scheduled Flow Best Practices](https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2022/01/18/scheduled-flow-best-practices/).

Comment: Vinay - thank you very much for this. I looked into the different Flow limits and considerations and tried to find if there was a limit to the number of queries which could be run either daily or monthly but couldn't find that. I will be running one scheduled flow nightly which will be running a query through about 150k records. Do you know if that would cause us to approach any limit for a system ? Thanks again.

Comment: It should be standard flow limits that includes the 100 SOQL, 150 DML limits, I don't see anything specific apart from above mentioned.

Comment: Are those limits referring to the number of SOQL & DML which can be run within each run of a Flow ? In my case, I would be running the Flow nightly on 100,000 records, but each Flow would have only one query and one field update. So would the limit kick in for that ?

Comment: Maximum of 50,000 records can be returned in a single query and this applies to flows as well.